# How to save nil into serialized attribute in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, serialization

I am upgrading an app to Rails 4.2 and am running into an issue where nil values in a field that is serialized as an Array are getting interpreted as an empty array. Is there a way to get Rails 4.2 to differentiate between nil and an empty array for a serialized-as-Array attribute?

Top level problem demonstration:

```
#[old_app]
 > Rails.version
 => "3.0.3"
 > a = AsrProperty.new; a.save; a.keeps
 => nil

#[new_app]
 > Rails.version
 => "4.2.3"
 > a = AsrProperty.new; a.save; a.keeps
 => []
```

But it is important for my code to distinguish between nil and [], so this is a problem.

The model:

```
class AsrProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :keeps, Array
  #[...]
end
```

I think the issue lies with Rails deciding to take a shortcut for attributes that are serialized as a specific type (e.g. Array) by storing the empty instance of that type as nil in the database. This can be seen by looking at the SQL statement executed in each app:

> [old_app]: INSERT INTO `asr_properties` (`lock_version`, `keeps`)
>   VALUES (0, NULL)

Note that the above log line has been edited for clarity; there are other serialized attributes that were being written due to old Rails' behavior.

> [new_app]: INSERT INTO `asr_properties` (`lock_version`)
>   VALUES (0)

There is a workaround: by removing the "Array" declaration on the serialization, Rails is forced to save [] and {} differently:

```
class AsrProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :keeps #NOT ARRAY
  #[...]
end
```

Changing the statement generated on saving [] to be:

> INSERT INTO `asr_properties` (`keeps`, `lock_version`) VALUES ('---[]\n', 0)

Allowing:

```
 > a = AsrProperty.new; a.save; a.keeps
 => nil
```

I'll use this workaround for now, but:
(1) I feel like declaring a type might allow more efficiency, and also prevents bugs by explicitly prohibiting the wrong data type being stored
(2) I'd really like to figure out the "right" way to do it, if Rails does allow it.

So: can Rails 4.2 be told to store [] as its own thing in a serialized-as-Array attribute?

Comment: My expectation, as a user of the code, would be that `a.keeps` SHOULD always return an array, and so you should tailor your code accordingly to expect it to always be an array rather than sometimes an array and sometimes nil.

Comment: But that is not consistent with other types stored in the database. You can have an integer type that returns nil, for example. NULL can be in any typed column in the database, so it would be more consistent both with existing behavior (with other types) and previous behavior (where nil could be stored) to allow storing and retrieving of NULL.

Comment: In the ruby world, not database, `:keeps` is not `nil` it is `empty`

Comment: Antarr, what do you mean? [] is empty but not nil, nil is nil and does not respond_to :empty?. Rails is saving both nil and [] as NULL in the db. Older version of Rails would save [] as [].to_yaml, which allowed you to distinguish between nil and [] (empty). Current Rails also saves [] as [].to_yaml if you serialize without a declared type. For any SQL-supported type, SQL NULL is retrieved as Ruby nil. Only not for type-specified serialized fields. So the behavior in current Rails, to me, is confusing.

Comment: Andrew you are right that other fields (eg integers and strings) can have a value or be nil.  But for me, with any method which returns an array, the convention is that if there is no information to be had then it should return an empty array rather than nil.  Arrays are very often used for data structure manipulation, for example being added, subtracted, intersected etc with other arrays, or having values pushed into them.  If the variable holding the array can sometimes be nil that forces the coders to write all sorts of extra exception handling which is a PITA.

Comment: I see your point, Max. Not sure I'm 100% behind it, but there's room for debate so I certainly don't expect Rails to necessarily implement it my way. In any case, I'll just serialize without the Array type, which will have to do for saying "this could be an Array or another type (in my case, NilClass or bust). Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What's going on?

What you're experiencing is due to how Rails 4 treats the 2nd argument to the `serialize` call. It changes its behavior based on the three different values the argument can have (more on this in the solution). The last branch [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.8/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb#L47) is the one we're interested in as when you pass the `Array` class, it gets passed to the `ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn` instance that is created. The `load` method receives the YAML from the database and attempts to turn it back into a Ruby object [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.8/activerecord/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb#L24). If the coder was not given the default class of `Object` and the `yaml` argument is `nil` in the case of a `null` column, it will return a new instance of the class, hence the empty array.

## Solution

There doesn't appear to be a simple Rails-y way to say, "hey, if this is `null` in the database, give me `nil`." However looking at the second branch [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.8/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb#L44) we see that we can pass any object that implements the `load` and `dump` methods or what I call the basic coder protocol.

#### Example code

One of the members of my team built this simple class to handle just this case.

```
class NullableSerializer < ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn
  def load(yaml)
    return nil if yaml.nil?          
    super
  end
end
```

This class inherits from the same `YAMLColumn` class provided by `ActiveRecord` so it already handles the `load` and `dump` methods. We do not need any modifications to `dump` but we want to slightly handle loading differently. We simply tell it to return `nil` when the database column is empty and otherwise call `super` to work as if we made no other modification.

#### Usage

To use it, it simply needs to be instantiated with your intended serialization class and passed to the Rails `serialize` method as in the following, using your naming from above:

```
class AsrProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :keeps, NullableSerializer.new(Array)
  # …
end
```

## The "right" way

Getting things done and getting your code shipped is paramount and I hope this helps you. After all, if the code isn't being used and doing good, who cares how ideal it is?

I would argue that Rails' approach is the right way in this case especially when you take Ruby's philosophy of The Principle of Least Surprise into account. When an attribute can possibly be an array, it should always return that type, even if empty, to avoid having to constantly special case `nil`. I would argue the same for any database column that you can put a reasonable default on (i.e. `t.integer :anything_besides_a_foreign_key, default: 0`). I've always been grateful to past-Aaron for remembering this most of the time whenever I get an unexpected `NoMethodError: undefined method 'whatever' for nil:NilClass`. Almost always my special case for this `nil` is to supply a sensible default.

This varies greatly on you, your team, your app, and your application and it's needs so it's never hard and fast. It's just something I've found helps me out immensely when I'm working on something and wondering if `amount` could default to `0` or if there's some reason buried in the code or in the minds of your teammates why it needs to be able to be `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation and neat solution! I guess I'm not 100% sure I agree that disallowing `nil` is least-surprise here, even though I have come to agree that it would be if all other columns could be made to behave similarly (right there with you on "does it makes sense for amount to be nil?"). But that's not the case: all SQL-native columns can be a value of their declared type or `nil`. That is, you either want `nil`s or have to nil-safe columns that return `Integer`s, so to me it's more surprising that columns that return `Array`s are different. Just a thought exercise.

Comment: You're welcome :). It's a good thing to think about and only you would know what will work _best_ with you project/team as there are many different things to optimize for. I haven't collected any actual data beyond my own experience on many projects with numerous team members of varying skill levels. I feel I've avoided a lot of bugs and extraneous code by having as tight a data design as possible but there's more to consider when storing non primitives in the database.

Comment: I tend to agree with the nil-able nature of a field. Booleans come back nil, not true false. Amounts can be be nil too.. How much did you pay for the house? You have a purchase record with state pending.  Amount should be nil. Even non-primitives would make sense to be nullable when they just aren't there yet.

Comment: I feel that `nil` is the biggest edge case in software these days. Even the inventor of the `null` type says it is his billion dollar mistake! Ultimately it puts the burden on the developer to determine _if_ a value can be `nil` and what it potentially means. There really isn't a one size fits all approach. Taking your example a step further, a pending home purchase could have a `nil` `amount` but a table payments should not have a `nil` `amount` (default of `0` could make sense but it's another arguable point).